# Error in if (any(co)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, svm, na

I am trying to build a model for one class classification using SVM in R. I have verified using `is.na(x)` that none of my objects have `NA` values. I keep getting the error for which I cannot find a solution to, despite many posts on this topic.

```
d<-read.xlsx("deals.xlsx", sheetIndex=1, rowIndex=NULL,
         startRow=2, endRow=200, colIndex=(1:5),
         as.data.frame=T, header=T, colClasses=NA,
         keepFormulas=FALSE, encoding="unknown")

d<-subset(d, res=="yes")
x <- subset(d, select = -res) #make x variables
y <- (d$res) #make y variable(dependent)

model <- svm(x,y,type='one-classification')
```

Answer (score 3):

Ran into a similar problem, and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688421/missing-value-where-true-false-needed-with-caret) was helpful. In short, my error was related to having two predictors of class `Date`, as well as two predictors of class `factor`. I'm using `{caret}` and calling a `{kernlab}` model for SVM. You could remove these variables, but if you'd like to keep them (or ones derived from them):

The linked thread includes a suggestion for creating a numeric variable out of the `Date` variable(s) to keep a date-like feature for modeling.

For predictors stored as factors, you could try something like the function below. The function will take the current `factor` variable name, then add a suffix of `_LEVEL`, where `LEVEL` is the name of the `factor` level. The original features are still preserved however, so you'd want to remove those either before modeling or during the modeling step (e.g. in a formula reference, exclude those columns with `x = df[, -c(1:2)]`).

Function:

```
for (i in colnames(df[, sapply(df, is.factor)])){
    for (level in unique(df[, i])){
        df[paste(i, level, sep = "_")] = 
            as.integer(ifelse(df[, i] == level, 1, -1))
    }
}
```

Substitute `df` for the name of your `data.frame` and you should be good to go.

Michael

Comment: For predictors as factors you can just use the formula interface directly, no need to create dummy variables by hand.

Comment: @Eduardo Correct me if I'm wrong, but doing that will automatically include n-1 levels of the factor, no? In some instances, I've found I only want to include certain levels of a factor rather than n-1. Michael

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and i found out that my x data frame contained a column with labeled values. I removed the column by doing:

```
x<- x[,-1] #where 1 is the number of the column
```

if you follow this example ([One-class classification with SVM in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375517/one-class-classification-with-svm-in-r)), and output the data sets, you will see that the initial dataset df contains the labeled values, then the x data frame does not and the y contains only labeled variables.